# AWS Amplify app as Cloudfront distribution origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

I have created an AWS Amplify app and I'd like to use the default generated url of the app which is something like this: https://shared.xxxxx.amplifyapp.com/ ("shared" being the branch name) as an origin in a Cloudfront distribution that I'd created separately.

The Cloudfront distribution has alternative domain names linked to it which are accessible but when I create a behavior in this distribution and point it to the Amplify origin mentioned before, and navigate to the path (alternative domain/behavior_path) the response is:

403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied

I would like to know if/how I can set up an Amplify app as an origin of a Cloudfront distribution.

Comment: Hi, any update or resolution? I am getting the same error for the same scenario. Thanks!

Comment: talking to their support engineer they told us that we can't have cloudfront in front of Amplify. This was the best answer we could get out of them. we've decided not to use Amplify.

Comment: I works for me (own CloudFront with amplify url as origin), I think the trick here is to use `AllViewerExceptHostHeader` Origin request policy in CloudFront you control 

I'm just wondering how to prohibit access to Amplify url directly

Comment: Thanks @romanlv it works exactly as I want

Answer (score 0):

If you have a different behavior setup for /* then make sure you setup the /assets/* behavior in cloudfront as the files for amplify are served from that directory. As when your initial document loads from amplify it will request your css and js from CURRENTDOMAIN.COM/assets/example.js|example.css